# Useless Bluetooth advertisement under Android?

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was actually using Cordova with *cordova-plugin-bluetoothle*, but I tend to think that this problem is related to Android more than Cordova.

I started a scan and in response got several devices, all with data similar to:

```
{
    "address":"38:CC:7A:F6:F5:AC",
    "name":null,
    "rssi":-74,
    "advertisement":"Hv8GAAEJIAAFQjB0jtGzjUXqNjOrWsBW+NPHv+y9swAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
    "status":"scanResult"
},
{
    "address":"4A:85:03:9A:F7:0C",
    "name":"\u0010",
    "rssi":-60,
"advertisement":"AgEGB/9MABACCwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
    "status":"scanResult"
}
```

Q1: Why am I getting an empty name or a cryptic \u0010? Shouldn't every BT device identify itself in a way that allows the user to select it?

Q2: The advertisement data seem to be useless! It is quite clear that it is in base64, but decoding the base64 was still giving useless data. I was trying to parse it using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bleadvertise), but the result of the parsing seems meaningless. I was investigating hours trying to solve it and find references in the internet, without success!

I will highly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Even, if your problem is solved now: You can check the advertisement payload with a 3rd party app. I use the nrf connect app, which is really great for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the explanation! It is the iBeacon advertisement format. See more in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon).

I also found this nice [advlib](https://github.com/reelyactive/advlib) library that did the parsing very well.